# VB.NET form resize

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

Good afternoon.
I'm having a problem resizing a listview in a form.

In the normal position the listview is placed correctly as you can see in the image.
[image: normal]

When i maximize the form, i get a huge space between the top controls and the listview.

[image]

How can i solve this situation, so the listview can expand and stay near the other controls?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the ListView's `Anchor` property to all four sides.